# How to work with limit that is function of other variable?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I had this question while working with solution manual of Rudin PMA. I am referring exer 3.14, part (c) and its solution as given [here](https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/67009/rudin%20ch%203.pdf?sequence=9).

> In that solution they consider convergence for $$\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$, as $n\to\infty$, where $k^3\le n< (k+1)^3$. The authors say that since $n\ge k^3$, we see that $\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{k(k+1)}{2}<\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k^2}$.  Now, $\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k^2}$ tends to zero as $k\to \infty$. Since $(k+1)^3>n$, it follows that $k$ tends to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity.

My question is, how do we derive  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ from above information?

Comment: Squeezing theorem. Also, as given, $n\to +\infty \iff k \to +\infty$.

Comment: @xbh, how to apply $n\to +\infty \iff k \to +\infty$ here? actually this is my first encounter to such problem, it will be big help if you can explain more.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$0\le \frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{k(k+1)}{2} \le \frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k^2}\to 0$$

and by squeeze theorem we can conclude that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{k(k+1)}{2} =0$$

Answer (score 1):

You just have to note that $n\geq k^3$ so that $k\leq n^{1/3}$ and then $$0\leq\frac{k(k+1)}{2(n+1)}\leq \frac{n^{1/3}(n^{1/3}+1)}{2(n+1)}$$ Now by squeeze theorem it follows that $k(k+1)/(2(n+1))\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: $\frac{n^{1/3}(n^{1/3}+1)}{2(n+1)}\le \frac{n^{1/3}(n^{1/3}+1)}{2n}=\frac{n^{1/3}+1}{2n^{2/3}}=\frac{n^{2/3}(n^{-1/3}+n^{-2/3})}{2n^{2/3}}=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}+\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}\Big)$ which tends to zero. Is this correct?

Comment: @BijeshK.S: it's correct but unnecessarily too long. Just note that highest power of $n$ in numerator is $2/3$ which is less than that in denominator.